# Drupal 7: Rename files on upload (via filefield)

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7, filefield, imagefield

I am looking for a way to rename files that are uploaded by users through a filefield. For example, rename user profile photos using `uniqid`.

I found a good solution for D6 at "[Drupal 6: How to Change Filename on Upload](http://www.wesjones.net/home/2011/03/drupal-6-how-to-change-filename-on-upload)" but can't find anything for D7.

Another option is to use [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths), but:

1. The module causes warnings on my setup.
2. Seems to be a bit of an overkill to install a general module for a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can change every file upload by [hook_file_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7) as your desire pattern
as example

```
function yourmodulename_file_presave($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $file->filename = 'mypattern_'.$file->uid .'_'. $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
}
```

**but this method do not rename filname(it just rename file name in file_managed table),** if you want also rename file name (uri of file) you should use below code

```
function hook_file_insert($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $uri = 'public://'.'mypattern_'.$file->uid .'_'. $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
  $file=file_move($file, $uri);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if you want to rename a filename (on disk) depending on it's type, let's say, only "documents", and you have 2 types that use *application/pdf* as mime type, in the very moment of uploading the file, it already has an internal type, which is not predictable (which seems to be a bug). But it prevents renaming files depending on their type (here I want tor rename *only* my custom file type *News*. Seems very tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Important part is the replacement of **SOMEFILENAME**

```
function MYMODULE_background_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
      'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg'),
  ));
  if ($file) {
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://**SOMEFILENAME**', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)) {
      $form_state['values']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
  }
}

function MYMODULE_background_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $file=$form_state['values']['file'];
  unset($form_state['values']['file']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
  drupal_set_message(t('Thanks, the background has been saved.'));
}
```